# Briefly explain how the Prolog program works?Consider the Prolog program given below

Tags: prolog, logic

```
test(X,[ ],0).

test(X,[H|T], N) :- H >= X, test (X,T,N1), N is N1+1.

test (X,[H|T], N) :- H < X, test (X,T,N).
```

Draw the search (derivation) tree for the following query using above Prolog program.

```
|?- test (7,[9, 5, 2, 10, 7,8], N) .
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a simple recursion: A predicate is called to itself with 3 different cases, this way it travels through the list comparing their elements with a given one (X).

The base case (1st predicate) is that the list is empty, so there's no element that can be greater or equal than the given one.
The second and third predicates compare the first element of the list (H) with the given one (X), in the case H is greater or equal than X, then we're in the second predicate so we sum 1 to the result of doing the same operation over the rest of the list. Otherwise if H is less than X then we return the result of applying the predicate over the rest of the list.

It's easy to see that for example calling

> test (2,[1,2,3], N) .

The N will be 2:

> test(2,[1,2,3],2) -> test(2,[2,3],2) -> test(2,[3],1) -> test(2,[],0).

Comment: Please send me answer for search tree